# How to write Html codes or \n into description of Gmail? PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Hello ive created a program that can send email with icalendar. But in the description part of Gmail looks like the same html codes which i wanted to implement. How can i write html codes into this section? Or at least i wanna learn how to use new line`(\n)` into that. It also doesnt read new line...Thanks.

```
    $cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";


    $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";


    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";


    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>Merhaba '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>'; 
    $message .= $meeting_name;    
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";

    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";


$ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
DTEND:'.$dtend.'
LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:'.$cal_uid.'
DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';   

    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;            

    //SEND MAIL
    $mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

    if($mail_sent)     {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this source

```
$subject = 'Website Change Request';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Read more about [Send email with HTML template PHP](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

You need `<br>`tags instead
you can convert `\n` or `\r\n` in your strings to `<br>` using `nl2br($string)`
check documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)